# How to use nmcli to always connect to vpn when using certain wifi?

Tags: arch-linux, networkmanager, openvpn, nmcli

Using nm-applet, it's quite easy to save a VPN connection and username+password of the connection and then automatically connect to it when using a certain Wi-Fi connection. It will always automatically connect to it without asking for passwords.

How to achieve this in the terminal using `nmcli` and other commands? I'm trying to script it to make it easier to deploy more connections and edit them.

So far I only managed to

```
nmcli connection import type openvpn file ned.ovpn
```

I also noticed that saved connections can be found at

```
 /etc/NetworkManager/system-connections/
```

I tried to copy the same settings from my laptop to my desktop but nothing seemed to change -- it didn't seem to see/change those settings.

Answer (score 12, accepted):

Here's a detailed explanation from my initial comment. The goal is to learn what is the equivalent using the CLI tool *nmcli* without having to browse through all the documentation to pinpoint a setting as long as it's known by the user on the GUI tool: with the temporary help of this GUI tool *nm-applet*, which has to be available *somewhere* (not even the same system) with an equivalent setup. This is just a generic method which could be used for any other setting than the one considered here.

There are two connections involved: I'll call them *main*, and *myVPN* which is to be automatically connected when using *main*. Here the change will be done on *main*, that's the one which must be examined.

```
$ nmcli connection show
NAME                UUID                                  TYPE       DEVICE 
main                cfa5be23-925a-4273-b5de-2f9adaac8782  wifi       --
myVPN               0d9e60ef-6b5e-4f65-8312-8db428589866  vpn        --
```

To display the configuration of main, either of these:

```
nmcli connection show id main
nmcli connection show uuid cfa5be23-925a-4273-b5de-2f9adaac8782
```

will dump among many other lines something like:

```
connection.id:                          main
connection.uuid:                        cfa5be23-925a-4273-b5de-2f9adaac8782
connection.type:                        802-11-wireless
```

[...]

So first dump *all* of it in a file. Some of the output is localized, so better do `export LANG=C.UTF-8` before (if later a specific setting name or value should be searched or compared on internet this would help):

```
nmcli c show id main > /tmp/before
```

Using the GUI tool *nm-applet* where the feature is known, the VPN *myVPN* is added to main:

[image: set VPN autoconnect]

Dump it *again*:

```
nmcli c show id main > /tmp/after
```

Now [`diff`](https://manpages.debian.org/diff.1) can compare and show what changed:

```
$ diff -u /tmp/before /tmp/after
--- /tmp/before 2019-05-04 10:47:43.410149358 +0200
+++ /tmp/after  2019-05-04 10:47:58.798252044 +0200
@@ -15,7 +15,7 @@
 connection.master:                      --
 connection.slave-type:                  --
 connection.autoconnect-slaves:          -1 (default)
-connection.secondaries:                 --
+connection.secondaries:                 0d9e60ef-6b5e-4f65-8312-8db428589866
 connection.gateway-ping-timeout:        0
 connection.metered:                     unknown
 connection.lldp:                        default
```

So that means the previously inconspicuous setting `connection.secondaries` got set, without too much trouble to guess, to *myVPN*'s UUID: `0d9e60ef-6b5e-4f65-8312-8db428589866`. [nm-settings(5)](https://developer.gnome.org/NetworkManager/stable/nm-settings.html) tells about it in *connection setting*:

> secondaries   array of string     []
>
> List of connection UUIDs that should be activated when the base
> connection itself is activated. Currently only VPN connections are
> supported.

You can now clear again any automatic connection to VPN on *main* with:

```
nmcli c modify id main connection.secondaries ''
```

and add again *myVPN* with (it's an array, hence `+`):

```
nmcli c modify id main +connection.secondaries 0d9e60ef-6b5e-4f65-8312-8db428589866
```

With some glue code (retrieving uuid from id etc.) this can now be automated.

Of course, the corresponding line is added or removed in a file somewhere in `/etc/NetworkManager/`, but this should not be relied upon.

NB: I didn't know about this setting before writing this answer, I just did what I told.

Comment: Thanks mate. Learned a lot from the way you do things. By testing the changes to see which is the part thats important. The only thing that troubles me is that the UUID changes everytime I reinstall computer or add a new vpn connection.

But then I guess I could somehow try to find out how to grep and sed